# Joomla JS file add

Tags: javascript, joomla

I want to remove this:
`<script src="/../../media/jui/js/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`

JS file from "media/jui" called by joomla head , but it is need to edit or remove. Where this js file added? 
**There is no script tag in my index.php file that added js from media/jui.** 
Only exist:

`<script src="<?php //echo $this->baseurl; ?>/media/jui/js/html5.js"></script>` that is disable.

Comment: Hi! Since some time, Joomla has its own StackExchange site: [joomla.stackexchange.com](http://joomla.stackexchange.com). I recommend you asking your future [tag:joomla]-related questions there.

Answer (score 0):

Look for the following in your template index.php file:

```
JHtml::_('jquery.framework');
```

or

```
JHtml::_('bootstrap.framework');
```

These are the Joomla methods used to import jQuery and Bootstrap. The bootstrap code also import jQuery so if this is the only one you see, then remove it

Comment: JHtml::_('jquery.framework'); and JHtml::_('bootstrap.framework'); are disable in index.php.